# How to increase reputation from 1 to 2 in Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

I want to ask some questions. But it says that I need a minimum reputation of 2 to do so. However I cannot find out any way to increase my reputation from 1 to 2. I am not experienced enough to answer questions in Meta Stack Exchange and gain reputation. Please help.

Comment: Suggest an edit to a post - make it a good change (formatting, spelling, grammar - all of the above if needed). When approved, you will gain 2 reputation.

Comment: @Louis Na. Not a dupe of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two options for you to increase your Meta Stack Exchange [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

- Edit a question or answer on Meta Stack Exchange; if the edit is approved, you will get +2 reputation.
- Earn 200 reputation on *any* Stack Exchange site; this will give you an association bonus of 100 reputation on *all other* sites, including Meta Stack Exchange.

<sub>A third, but unlikely, option is that you post a question/answer on another site (e.g. this one), get some upvotes and the question gets subsequently migrated to Meta Stack Exchange.</sub>

Comment: @RobertLongson They do.

Comment: The third option will probably happen as this is way off scope here. (or is now)

Comment: @Peanut correct, but OP needs *upvotes* on a question for that to help him.